# Fiat to Satoshi Relationship

Tags: buy-bitcoins, satoshi, fiat

Is there a formula to calculate the fiat value of a Satoshi using your fiat principle?

Answer (score 5):

The number of satoshi per bitcoin is `1e8` or `100,000,000`, so if you have a fiat value per bitcoin such as `$7000/BTC`, the calculation is:

`$/satoshi = $7000/1e8 = $0.00007 per satoshi`

Of course, there is no fixed fiat to satoshi value because the fiat value of Bitcoin is determined by the market, i.e. exchange value.